# How to format the text like this?

Tags: formatting

How to format the text like this:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) There are multiple options. What have you tried so far?

Comment: You could use an appropriately set up `description` environment, a `tabular` or `minipages`,...

Comment: i am beginner in tex, i coudint find a way to apply the name under and above in the same row. well thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to use `tabularx`, you may try other options as @leandriis suggested in a comment.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}            

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\noindent%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\bfseries}lX@{}}
   Engineering mechanics & - Irving H. Shames, G. Krislina. Mohana Rao \\
   Textbook              & - R. K. Ban sal, Sanjay Ban sal IrvUi H. Shames, J. Benjamin\\
   Reference             & - S. Rajasekharan, G. Sankara Subramanyan R.C. Hibbler
\end{tabularx}  

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: I'd suggest using `@{ - }` or something similar as the column delimiter between the two columns to get closer to the image shown by OP.

Comment: Also I'd suggest using `\raggedright` in the second column.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, because it is so seldomly used, a solution using the `tabbing` environment:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
  \textbf{Engineering mechanics} \=- \=Irving H. Shames, G. Krishna. Mohana Rao \\
  \textbf{Textbook}\>-\>R. K. Bansal, Sanjay Bansal \\
  \>\>Irvin H. Shames, J. Benjamin \\
  \textbf{Reference}\>-\>S. Rajasekharan, G. Sankara Subramanyan \\
  \>\>R. C. Hibbler
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: oh, this is cool